# compile project ,build_native.sh can't find my ndk files

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

my command compile game project

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=”E:/sdk”
export NDK_ROOT=”E:/ndk”
cd E:/proj.android
sh build_native.sh
```

ndk-build exist in that directory actually. 
when I compile my project.

```
$ sh build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = ”E:/ndk”
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/e/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/e/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/e/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
build_native.sh: line 75: ”E:/ndk”/ndk-build: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try moving COCOS2DX to /cygdrive/e/ I faced similar problems when the dependancies were deep inside folder structure. Move everything to E:/

Comment: how i move COCOS2DX_ROOT to e drive and everything copy and paste file? i'm not sure how they get COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/e/proj.android/../../.. i didnt type any command